# Gunicorn is timeout and no logs in error files

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am running django application serving with nginx and gunicorn in supervisor,I am getting gunicorn timeout 
errors in gunicorn error logs but don't know what causing the errors.

```
2018-10-01 20:20:19 [20529] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:20646)
2018-10-01 20:20:19 [23948] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23948
```

Is there a way we can configure gunicorn to write logs entry before the gunicorn process is timeout and killed ?

Comment: [Most solutions](https://serverfault.com/a/627746) I can find seems to be about increasing the timeout value. Can you include your current Gunicorn config file in your question?

Comment: Please post your nginx config and your WSGI file please, it will help to eliminate some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by increasing the timeout value to a bigger value than the default 30sec